# I'm trying to get a menu list with the effect fade to (jquery)

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".menu li a").hover(function() {
$(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
});
});
```

I want to effect mouseover and mouseout but I can't do it :(

Comment: Please add specifics.  What doesn't work? Can you show us an example, or set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    $(".menu li a").hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    }, function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: @Dante85 - you have to be much more specific than "doesn't work".  Is there an error? Are you sure you're loading jQuery and jQuery easing?  Does your html have the appropriate classes? I would encourage you to use a tool such as Firebug (for Firefox) to troubleshoot the javascript - it' super powerful/helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I found the correct code, I don't know why your code did not work: $(document).ready(function(){
$(".menu a").fadeTo("slow", 0.3);
$(".menu a").hover(function(){
$(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.3);
},function(){
$(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.3);
});
});

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".menu li a").hover(function() {

      // do something for mouseover

   }, function() {

     // do something for mouseout

   });
});
```